# How can i change tick val to title in ChartJS

Tags: chart.js, chart.js3

[image]

Hello tell please how is possible show text title instead int values, look at pic,

ChartJS ver.3

Answer (score 0):

You can override the tick callback, so you check the value of the tick and instead of returning that value you return the string of text you want to return

```
options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return valueToString(value);
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
```

Source: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats